# Can I use Timer with no Timer Component?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, timer

I'm working with a windows service and they are so hard to test, so would like to leave it as a empty as possible only importing classes.

I need to use a **Timer** to trigger and event every 5 minutes, but if i use the timer component i have to place it on my windows service.

**So is it possible to build my own basic timer class ??**

How would i go about this? i want to to be very small and light, a few lines of code if possible.

Comment: Windows Services should *not* use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` control anyway.

Comment: Cool ok so i am doing the write thing about doing this in a class? and then just useing the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) or [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

```
// Create a timer with a ten second interval.
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

// Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
aTimer.Interval = 2000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Timer elapsed event handler

```
// Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is 
// raised.
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

You wont be requiring timer component in this case

[Here is the complete article on Timers in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S3). Complete comparison between different type of timers is discussed here.

Comment: Thanks for the link i checked out System.Timers.Timer So this will work with no timer componet, Just code?

Comment: @Pomster you don't need timer component in this case

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer ? That should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok i looked up  System.Timers.Timer, and read up the first google search. now this will work with no timer componet??

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep(1000*60*5); // filler because my answer is too small and light otherwise.

.. or, to make it more 'Timer-ish' add a for loop:

```
for(;;){
  timerEvent();
  Thread.Sleep(1000*60*5);
};
```

Comment: OK, so I added a loop to call an event.  Now it looks like a timer.

Comment: Except looks can be deceiving. `Thread.Sleep` is a *blocking* call for the entire thread. That's quite different from a timer.

Comment: It's small, light, has few lines of code and does not require any code or locking to handle signalling from a pool thread or any message-loops to work.  Yes, it blocks the caller and, if this is an issue, better not use it.

Comment: I don't see those caveats mentioned in your answer. The person who asked the question is in search of a *timer*. That concept implies certain things which your solution does not satisfy. Perhaps your solution would *also* be workable, but you need to make clear that it is not exactly the same thing as a timer and how it's different.

Comment: There is only one caveat, and it should be fairly obvious.  What is the definition of a timer anyway?  The Wiki definition encompasses a blocking sleep() loop.  Another I found was 'A timer is an object that can be used in your applications to cause an event to occur on a specified interval.'  Anyway, the alernatives are System.Timers or Threading.Timers, both of which require more lines of code.